# Where is the activeCameraController and is there a .keyPanEnabled in it

Tags: roblox

So I was trying to make a free camera script that uses the arrow keys. But It won't work. I searched on google and found https://devforum.roblox.com/t/getting-leftright-arrow-key-inputs/726916. I scrolled through it and found this comment:

> The Left and Right Arrow Keys are grabbed by the camera and uses UserInputService as well,
> ie. They aren’t bound with ContextActionService.
> **But there is a flag that can prevent the camera from grabbing the left and right arrows for panning.
> You’ll have to grab the activeCameraController and then set its .keyPanEnabled to false.**
> (Something to research, or maybe someone else will take the time to explain it more.)

I was a bit confused of where the .keyPanEnabled was, I don't even know where the activeCameraController is. I couldn't find anything. I tried using "Find" tool and searching the CameraModules but it did not work. Can someone please tell me how to get the .keyPanEnabled and the activeCameraController?

Comment: I can't find any reference to this anywhere. Even sarching through all of the camera scripts that are placed on your character when you play the game hasn't revealed anything

Comment: So its all in the corescripts?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: To keep it straight, where is the activeCameraController